# string format in php

Tags: php, string

Basically I want to assing this `');"`  string to a variable but it is giving error. I'm working on Netbeans

error:

```
Syntax error

unexpected: '"'

after:  String '"');"'

expected:instanceof, as, =>, }, ',', OR, XOR, &&, ?, ;, ||, &&, |, ^, &, ==, !=, ===, !==, <=,   >=, <, >, <<, >>, +, -, *, /, %, '.', ], ), :
```

like

```
$my_string = `"ı');""`
```

what I am missing? I think quotes

Comment: the error and your $my_string variable give you all the pointers you need!. there's too many "

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the characters in the string:

```
$my_string = "ı');\"";
```

With this:

```
echo $my_string;
```

Output:

```
ı');"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
$my_string = "ı');\"";
```

You need to escape the `"`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the 2nd to last `"`.

```
"ı');\""
```